# What are the main arguments against White Nationalism?

Tags: racism, nationalism

[The Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_nationalism) of the term 'white nationalist' is "A type of nationalism or pan-nationalism which holds the belief that white people are a race and seeks to develop and maintain a white national identity."

In light of the recent events in Charlottesville, this ideology is facing a lot of criticism in the media.

What are the main arguments made by notable opponents of White Nationalism against this ideology? Please add a source for each argument you mention in your answers.

Comment: If anyone has further comments which are not about improving this question but rather about voting behavior, moderation or any other meta-topic, please discuss it on https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Stop the Back and forth edit fights over the Tags. White nationalism is viewed as the Far Right by those on the Right, and as racism by the majority of the populace.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I'm not having racism put in my tags when the post isn't directly related to racism. I think that's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: This question isn't yours anymore; it exists on politics.se, licensed under Creative Commons, and collaboratively edited. "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you." Reference: https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: @Charlie white nationalism *is* racism.

Comment: @DrunkCynic you're being deliberately confrontational. Adding the tag "racism" does nothing but try and further your own political agenda. It is the deliberate and reasonless biasing of question tags. It serves no purpose but to cause a reaction or socially engineer the opinions of others. White nationalism, as we have established, is not in of itself racism, just in the same way that a post about Communism wouldn't warrant the tag "Gulag". If we are simply assigning tags on the basis of what the question's conscept may lead to, then that system must be amended.

Comment: Tags aren't to color the question, or to influence response; they are there to support question archiving and ability to be searched.

Comment: @DrunkCynic no one is going to be searching racism and wanting to look into white nationalism. They are related but distinct topics. If this was about arguments against white supremacism, then you could add the tag "racism" but it isn't.

Comment: Unless it can be proven that White Nationalism isn't also White Supremacy/Separatism, which the linked question couldn't do, the accepted definition that White Nationalism is just a euphemism for White Supremacy stands. It was introduced by White Supremacists to soften their image for main stream consumption, yet they are still racist.  Link: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23652/are-there-any-notable-white-nationalists-that-arent-white-supremacists

Comment: @DrunkCynic the two aren't the same, one is the idea that white people are a superior race, the other that what whites should be entitled to a nation of their own and are entitled to maintain a national identity. Through strong borders and selective migration it is possible to have a white nation without genocide/expulsion shaming of other races. I can respect that other races are equal to my race whilst maintaining that they aren't entitled to my ancestral homeland. I think your US heritage has coloured your perception of white nationalism. For a country like the US founded...

Comment: @DrunkenCynic on multiculturalism white nationalism is nonsensical as you have no ancestral entitlement, but here in the UK white Celts have lived in Britain for 50'000 years, and hence maintaining that is not the issue it is in the US. US white nationalism is synonymous with racism, European white nationalism is not.

Comment: @charlie I repeat, white nationalism *is* racism. It's a term coined *by* racists to push their political agenda of *racism*. It was originally a dog whistle term.

Comment: Also white people living in a white country thinking they are 'entitled' to push out non-whites is...you guessed it...racist.

Comment: @Charlie Since the alt-right is getting a lot of attention, I created that tag and added it here. I think that splits the difference between this and the racism tag. If it won't suffice, please make a Meta post

Comment: @Machavity I think that makes sense as it is actually helpful for people searching.

Comment: @Blip no one said anything about "pushing people out".  In Britain, white nationalism is about selective immigration and strong borders. There is no need to push people out. And if you believe that an ethnic group who have lived on their land for the best part of 50'000 are not entitled to their homeland then I can't help you. Though in fairness, being American it is understandably hard for you to comprehend that certain ethnic groups have a birthright to land.

Comment: @charlie you don't need to help me with anything. I understand what you are saying. Perhaps you need to rethink the term you are using, because the term you are using is universally considered racism.

Comment: @blip no it isn't. Racism would be considering one race superior to another, I'm not doing that at all. However, certain races/ethnic groups have rights to land and that should be respected. Just in the same way I'm against what the US migrants did to the natives, the UK and the Boers did to the Zulus. I am racially consistent in my beliefs. Just in the same way I expect the right to the land of my people respected, I wouldn't wish other ethnic and racial groups to lose their culture and homeland either, it has nothing to do with one race being better than another.

Comment: @blip I think the confusion lies in that you think all White Nationalism is US white nationalism.

Comment: No.If by UK white nationalism, you could refer to the British National Party, which has a history of biological racism and white genocide conspiracy theory, than UK white nationalism should properly be considered racist.

Comment: @DrunkCynic as if it wasn't abundantly clear, you cannot judge the validity of a belief based on the character of a group of practitioners, that's a blatant generalisation. Not all white nationalists are BNP members so the argument is moot. The BNP isn't taken seriously in the UK anyway by anyone, they are a group of hooligans that masquerade as a political party and don't represent an entire belief system. Most British conservatives believe to some degree in white nationalism.

Comment: @DrunkenCynic most conservatives I know believe in putting the people of this country who are citizens first, and jobs should go to people born in Britain first as a rule.

Comment: To the first: That is who you're judged by, and the brush your opponents will paint you with. You wont' end the connection. Any political movement where the central driver is skin complexion of hereditary characteristics will always be referenced to Nazis and bigotry.

Comment: @DrunkCynic maybe where you're from, not here.

Comment: @DrunkCynic you don't understand the European climate

Comment: The European climate *invented* white nationalism.

Comment: @blip yes it did, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: One more original argument by Jordan Peterson - it means instead of condemning  left wing identititarian and collectivist position, actually embracing their anti-individualistic stance and trying to beat them at their own game. Effectively getting a nasty result one way or the other.  https://youtu.be/JK-l2tgMQRQ?t=634

Answer (score 19):

**What is White Nationalism**

The ADL definition:

> White nationalism is a term that originated among white supremacists as a **euphemism for white supremacy**. Eventually, some white supremacists tried to distinguish it further by using it to refer to **a form of white supremacy that emphasizes defining a country or region by white racial identity** and which seeks to promote the interests of whites exclusively, typically at the expense of people of other backgrounds. <sub>[ADL: White Nationalism](https://www.adl.org/education/resources/glossary-terms/white-nationalism)</sub>

The SPLC uses the following definition:

> **White nationalist groups espouse white supremacist or white separatist ideologies**, often focusing on the alleged inferiority of non-whites. 
>   Groups listed in a variety of other categories - Ku Klux Klan, neo-Confederate, neo-Nazi, racist skinhead, and Christian Identity - could also be fairly described as "white nationalist."<sub>[SPLC: White Nationalists](https://www.splcenter.org/fighting-hate/extremist-files/ideology/white-nationalist)</sub>

**What do White Nationalists want?**

As seen in the definitions above, the goal of white nationalist is a racially pure or white-dominated country.

Depending on their ideology, this can happen by subjugating, expelling, or murdering Jews, black people, and all others they deem racially inferior.

**Why are some opposed to White Nationalism**

Most of the opposition against white nationalism is based on moral grounds.

Some hold the idea that [all people should be equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_equality), regardless of race. In the US, this was codified into law with the fourteenth amendment (among other). This idea is in direct conflict with white nationalism, which seeks white dominance.

Some also oppose the violence from white nationalists. Charlottesville mayor for examples [stated](http://thehill.com/homenews/sunday-talk-shows/346378-charlottesville-mayor-were-not-seeing-leadership-from-the-white): "People are dying, and I do think that it's now on the president and on all of us to say enough is enough. This movement has run its course."

Those that are directly targeted additionally oppose white nationalism as it threatens their safety and well-being (see for example the [NAACP](http://www.naacp.org/latest/naacp-condemns-unite-the-right-hate-rally-in-charlottesville-virginia/)).

Comment: I think the only thing I'd add to this answer is the idea of countries like the US being a 'melting pot' of cultures/races. Essentially, that many people find value in minority groups, whereas white nationalists do not. I think the idea that minority cultures are causing more harm than good is at the core of the white nationalist movement, and it's somewhat different than the issue of equal rights, as well as the root cause of the violence.

Comment: "As seen in the definitions above, the goal of white nationalist is a racially pure or white-dominated country." Wouldn't it be better to use statements by actual white nationalists rather than groups who oppose them to determine what they want?

Comment: @eyeballfrog No, I don't think so. The question is specifically about those that oppose white nationalism. Even if their claims were wrong, they would be valid as an answer, while whatever white nationalists do or do not say is not.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Apart from that, white nationalists know that for example calling for the genocide of Jews is not popular and will hurt their message, which is why they usually use dog whistles and euphemisms instead. I mean, I could cite Richard Spencer and his comments about "peaceful" ethnic cleansing, or David Dukes ideas on the "Jewish Question", but then I would get comments doubting their relevance to white nationalism or the meaning of the specific quotes. I think that the definition of organizations that are experts on the topic are much more useful.

Comment: @tim Ah, good point on that first comment. I missed the restriction of the question to opponents' arguments in the body of the question. I'm a little skeptical of the idea of dogwhistles, though. They tend to just be ways to put words in peoples' mouths, and it's not like Spencer, Duke, and their ilk need any help impugning themselves.

Comment: And why exactly is a progressive left wing ADL (which never met left wing antisemite they hesitated to criticize) considered an authoitative source? How about your quote JDL, or let's say right wing Jews as authoritative source on the topic?

Comment: @user4012 quick history lesson: Jewish people have some experience with white supremacists. They've decided it'd be a good idea to have a vested interest in paying attention to them. SPLC has a long track record of being a monitor of all sorts of various hate groups. But you know all of this, of course.

Comment: @blip - I'm Jewish. I don't need your condescending lessons. I also know more about antisemitism from personal experience than everyone in ADL combined. REAL antisemitism, not "my feelings got hurt once" that American liberals are afraid of. SPLC labeled a bunch of normal right wing people "extremists" before. They have zero credibility with me at this point, same as ADL - they are basically carrying water for liberal political wing, not their stated mission.

Comment: @user4012 You don't need my condescending lesson, but you get what you give, so... :)

Comment: @user4012 1) As I said before, the question is specifically about the arguments by opponents, that's why I'm quoting opponents. 2) It's not relevant, but the ADL does mention antisemitism on the left; ironically, because of this - and it's strong stand against "antizionism" - antisemites on the left accuse it of being a right-wing organization.

Comment: @user4012 - Really, DVK? Do you think you know more about anti-Semitism because you’re Jewish, and have thus experienced it personally? Fair argument - but there are many Jewish people in the ADL, too. Do you think you know more about anti-Semitism because you’ve studied it extensively? Maybe you have (though I thought Perl was your specialty, not social sciences), but so have many people at the ADL. I’ve noticed that in your politics answers you rarely fail to take a jab at “the left,” which is a shame, because your answers are pretty knowledgeable.

Comment: Is it possible that you believe yourself to have superior knowledge because you grew up in a country where overt anti-Semitism was more common than in the US? But the ADL is large, and I’d be surprised if they didn’t have members from countries with more anti-Semitism than the US, or likely even from whatever country you hail from. The truth really seems to be that you *don’t* know more about anti-Semitism than “everyone in ADL combined,” and that you instead disagree on how to label or combat it. The intellectually honest thing to do would be to admit that.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - whichever of their top leadership I could google, all were born and raised Americans. I stand by my estimate, absent facts to the contrary.

Comment: @user4012 - With respect, I've met some Jews who believe that the opinions of other people on (say) Israel don't matter because they aren't part of the "in-group." That's silly. Your opinion that (for example ) only Russian Jews have *really* experienced anti-Semitism is even more tremendously narrow-minded. I'm sure that your experiences were real and painful - but they don't make you some sort of godlike expert on anti-Semitism.

Comment: Plus, it's funny to see a rather conservative individual using the same arguments as some of the more radical liberal factions.

Comment: In a deeply ironic twist, your personal experience might be claimed (not by me, but by the same argument that you used) to *devalue* your own knowledge of anti-Semitism in the US. The argument would go that maybe you understand how things work in country X, but the ADL members are Jews born and raised in the US, so their personal experience is more relevant. Fortunately, *I* don't believe this. :)

Comment: The truth is that having experienced anti-Semitism does impart some knowledge thereof. But it's not automatically superior to years of study, let alone so vastly superior as you seem to imagine. It would be smart to admit that just *maybe* someone could know as much (or even...dare I say it?...*more* about anti-Semitism than you, while possessing different opinions about it. After all, it's the same courtesy I extend to you.

Comment: Expanding on that last point, your answers (both on topics where you seem to draw on your personal experience and on those where you don't) indicate great knowledge of what you're talking about. But despite admitting that you know more than I do about them, I still sometimes disagree. See how it works?

Comment: @Obie2.0 - I always fight fire with fire. I fight post modernism with post modernism, identity politics with identity politics.

Comment: @blip Neither the ADL nor the SPLC are reliable sources. They're far-left organizations who have fairly nonsensical standards for what's considered "hateful". Notice how the ADL, for instance,  has never called out Netanyahu for his [anti-Arab racism](https://www.timesofisrael.com/netanyahus-arab-droves-warning-may-have-been-decisive-in-his-victory/). The SPLC isn't [much better](http://www.nationalreview.com/article/449476/splc-dangerous-lies-alliance-defending-freedom-no-hate-group). Furthermore, notice how you've blurred the line between "white supremacist" and "white nationalist".

Comment: @tim "antisemites on the left"? Like whom? And you seem to suggesting that anti-Zionist leftism critical of the far-right policies of the current Israeli government is anti-Semetic. What a gross slur.

Comment: @Obie2.0 The ADL is an organization with a particular agenda (e.g., demonization of American/European right-wing groups whom they don't consider sufficiently liberal whilst supporting right-wing policies in the Zionist state). They are not representative of all American Jews (particularly on the issue of Israel), and their opinion is hardly authoritative given their ideological leanings. user4012's criticisms are fair.

Comment: @MathematicsSrudent1122 I didn't blur any lines. There are no lines. White nationalist is just what white supremacists call themselves.

Comment: Also, a national review opinion piece is hardly proof of anything beyond a conservative viewpoint.

Answer (score 3):

[US White nationalists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIrcB1sAN8I) are controversial because their ideologies are close to those of the KKK and the Nazis, as spelt out in the Criticism section of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_nationalism#Criticism) on the topic. In case you need further convincing, the first link is a video so you can see and hear the connection first hand.

The Nazis are hopefully not controversial. In case they are, [the Holocaust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Holocaust) is one of the crimes they committed while in power. It took [a deadly world war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II_casualties) for non-nationalists to stop them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63907/discussion-on-answer-by-denis-de-bernardy-what-are-the-main-arguments-against-wh).

Answer (score 3):

I will assume this refers to white nationalism in a multi-ethnic country; as ethnic nationalism in a mono-ethnic country is implicit unless the country is unusually cosmopolitan.

Since this question would relate to the resurgent visibility of US White Nationalism; the counter-arguments to preserving/restoring a white-majority country with some arbitrary set of white cultural characteristics are:

1. A multi-ethnic multicultural society is a done deal. You would have to hurt a great many people to revert to a mono-cultural society.
2. A lot of people want to treat others according to their character not their race. A society that no longer aspires to that would horrify and dispirit a lot of people. A tangible negative outcome since our country is only as good as how we treat each other.
3. It's unclear that even if you could wave a magic wand (*expecto genocidia*) and achieve a mono-cultural mono-ethnic society, that it would be a healthy or happy one. Most such societies historically or today are not (cause or effect, who can say). There's always more [levels of purity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Inquisition) to strive for; always someone born within the country to hurt. You end up fighting human nature and sentient diversity itself.

So cost is very high and the pay-out is very low. And deontologically it's wrong.

Comment: @nice answer. I think point 3 may benefit from a few more links to validate it relevancy, as I think that one is a bit more on the speculative end. Perhaps link to a specific group that believes this would happen, a Wikipedia page or the like. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

The most important arguments against white nationalism result from the definition you gave:

> A type of nationalism or pan-nationalism which holds the belief that **white people are a race** and seeks to develop and **maintain a white national identity**.

- **White people are a race:** 
  it is not true. It does not mean that there are no ethnical differences between people, but that it is not possible to define precisely a race. In Western Europe, Arabic people are not seen as white, while in America they are described as Caucasian - that is the same category as any other white. When do you stop to be white?
- **Maintain a white national** population: to do that, you need to restrict the rights of foreigners to come in your country,
  which most States do, but also to forbid wedding with foreigners, or at least to limit the freedom of your own population. And what do you do with people of other "races" already living in the country? You do not have a lot of solutions: killing them, deporting them, limiting their rights...
- **a white national identity:** national identity is not a matter of colour. In "What is a nation?", Renan defines a nation as people that share history and want to live and act together, as opposed to a "race". A white American and a white Russian share less history than a white and a black American. You said that there has been *white* Celtic people in UK for 50 000 years, but actually you only know that there has been Celtic people in UK for 50 000 years. I would be very surprised if you had any proof that those Celtic weren't black, or asian, or anything else for their first 30 000 years in UK. The culture they transmitted remains, not their skin colour.

Comment: I think this is a good answer overall.

Comment: Arabic is not a race: It's a language and a culture.  There are people of various races who also happen to be Arabs.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Arabs are the people with ancestry in Arabia, as distinct from their neighbors the Turks, the Persians and the Egyptians. Cf. Arab in Wikipedia. Like everything, the boundaries are weak, but the extremes are clear. I'd be interesting in seeing evidence that someone with all recent Northern European or Japanese or sub-Saharan African ancestry might be considered an Arab.

Comment: @prosfilaes, I'd like to believe that I was parroting some actual authority on the subject when I wrote those words. But that was six years ago. I don't remember, and I am no authority on Arab culture. I like to believe that since then, I've learned to give credit to those people whose ideas I repeat.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to try to do this from a political theory perspective and attempt to cut the generalizing of a group as much as possible i.e. No "It's bad because Nazi's did it" it's true and a sore point but not a contemporary argument nor is blaming a concept for who is practicing it. What is important is the impact and results, which personally tend to be gross disenfranchisement and dehumanization which can lead to great atrocities if pushed too far WW2 and The Middle East are great examples. This goes for all forms of ethnocentric nationalism, even Africa has had it's share of genocides over this

Albeit generalizing political theory tends to get more criticism than just individual bias so yeah I'll make a chat and place it below for arguments and amend my answer after debate or arguments if you are unhappy with the categorization.

Now having braced myself for the coming storm

**[Marxist](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Marxist-view-of-nationalism)**

White Nationalism in Western Culture is the people in power saying they want to stay in power over those with less power. As such it can be seen that the bourgeoisie is stating that they do not want to let go of power and implies potential harm for those not White in the White Nation. Where as other ethnocentric forms of nationalism are then seen as Equalist movements to balance the roles of power and revolting against the oppressors, see Malcom X for instance. Marx himself did not particularly care about Nationalism in general though just so that Inter-Nationalism could bring down Captialism as such a perspective on class struggles should be able to better explain this point

**[Libertarian](https://mises.org/blog/libertarian-view-nationalism-secession-and-ethnic-enclaves)** [L1](http://reason.com/blog/2017/02/17/trumps-anti-libertarian-ethno-nationalis), a bit complicated

Left leaning Libertarians tend to feel that nationalism is a bi-product of groups however ethnocentric nationalism may imply potential harm placing undo stress unto the other groups though that would be further left Libertarians with the more center left would just say it is fine so long as it is not violating Nonaggression principle

Right leaning Libertarians may argue that nationalism has no place in a free society as all have the right of movement, but would ignore it should it arise as again Nonaggression principle

**[Centrist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrism)**

Centrist would see that social equality is balanced and to such extent would find White Nationalism unappealing and wrong as it puts one man on top of another due to simple birth factors.

**[Fascist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascism#Nationalism)** - Tends to be called Extreme Nationalism

Government mandated law on what it considers worthwhile people in the government. What constitutes "worthwhile" is up to the ruling party, as such could be viewed as good could be viewed as gulag worthy. At it's roots though it is bred from the concept of Nationalism.

**[Socialist](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Marxist-view-of-nationalism)**

Socialistic tend to share a Marxist PoV just with less of an oomph and more economic freedom for the individual. Though a gross over simplification like most things here all I can say is... see Marxism

Please note in many ideologies all forms of ethnocentric nationalism are looked down upon. Just because a media organization is saying something does not make it the primary standpoint of an ideology. Media loves ratings and shocking concepts generate ratings

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63883/white-supremacy-relating-to-political-theory

Comment: This is all fine, but not sure how it answers the question. (Unless we're talking about nationalism in general...but I think we're talking specifically about US-based 'white nationalism' which is a rather specific thing)

Comment: @blip The reasons these ideologies are opposed tends to be the influencing nature of why people reject these kind of concepts. The base philosophy drives moral standard/ethics after all IMO. Two people could be against the same thing but for different reasons/rational and these attempt to explain that rational and as such can be viewed as the root of this disposition.

Comment: Hmm...OK. That makes sense. An interesting addition to the answers.

Answer (score 1):

> The Wikipedia definition of the term 'white nationalist'

also states...

> White separatism and white supremacy are subgroups of white nationalism. Separatists seek a white-only state; supremacists believe that white people are superior to nonwhites,[4] taking ideas from social Darwinism and Nazism.[7]

A lot of people do not like Social Darwinism proponents, White Supremacists, Racists and Nazis. Hence the controversy regarding groups like this.

Comment: "White nationalism is a term that originated among white supremacists as a euphemism for white supremacy." (Tim's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

The most recent [Philip Defranco Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RHBiRnWwRs), of August 14 2017, summarize a central viewpoint as to why white nationalism is permanently associated with White Supremacy, Nazi's, KKK, etc. It is possible that there is a subset that hold white nationalist view points that don't adhere to the ideals of white supremacy. Even in that eventuality, they're doomed by the overriding cultural understanding.

White nationalists are impugned by the people standing next to them; from the recent activities in Charlottesville, preceding the vehicular homicide, there was the "Unite the Right" pre-rally march on the University of Virginia Campus. Among the white nationalists were white supremacists and Nazi's chanting Zieg Heil and throwing out Nazi Salutes.

The concept of a passive, "we just want to help ourselves," white nationalism is forever tainted by its associations with white supremacy, much like the passive ends of the Black Lives Matter movement and their more violent ends, or progressive protestors and Anti-Fa.

On the last, AntiFa and White Nationalists only differ in those they wish to extol; past that, there are more [similarities](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-9--B4Jhts&feature=share) than either group would admit. [Ben Shapiro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67zCG-KPWfQ) does well to highlight the violence between AntiFa and the White Supremicists in Charlottesville and the mob rule that occurred. The Alt Right/White Supremicists are bad for the US republic. AntiFa is bad for the US republic.

You are ruined by the worst among you.

Comment: An honest sincere answer but we need to stop equating Nazis with those *against* Nazis. You are correct that the worst of any group often taint the whole. But White Nationalists *are* the worst of the group. They are simply white supremacists using a different name. They didn't invite the worst...they are a part of the worst. The best white supremacist is still a far below the worst anti-nazi.

Comment: @blip Perspective: AntiFa and White Nationalists have the similar goals, tactics, disregard for the Constitution, and embrace of strong fascistic government, just with different groups along for the ride. The violence in Charlottesville was mutual, up until the vehicular murder. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-9--B4Jhts&feature=share

Comment: Perspective: AntiFa is but one small subset of those opposing unite-the-right groups. To imply everyone against Nazis are AntiFa is the disingenuous part of the logic. It's a form of victim blaming.

Comment: @blip It is not my intention to imply everyone against Nazi's are antifa; that be claiming I'm antifa. Thus the specific differentiation between progressive protestors and antifa. In the question, I'm providing for the possibility that their may be a segment of white nationalism that isn't white supremacy; slim though it may be.

Comment: I do believe that may not be your intention. However, that absolutely is the intention of a lot of current white nationalist sympathizers. They are trying as hard as they can to make their false equivalency sound legitimate (that anyone against nazis are just as bad as nazis). As for there being a slim non-racist segment of white nationalist...that's just wouldn't make sense. If  one isn't racist, then hopefully one isn't joining a racist group.

Comment: @blip There in lies the problem with banner political groups. The fringes of either side want to paint the entire opposition with its fringe, while cloaking themselves with the mainstream of their side. Everyone against the Left(Antifa) is a Nazi(Right), while everyone against the Right(Nazi) is an Antifa(left).

Comment: @DrunkCynic but we're not talking about the broad right. We're talking about this very specific fringe subset of unite-the-right. They *are* the fringe (well, I hope they are...I'd hate for them to become the core of the right).

Comment: @DrunkCynic The goal of white nationalists is a racially pure country - either by subjugating, expelling, or murdering Jews, black people, and all others they deem racially inferior. The goal of the antifa is to stop fascists. I don't see how those goals are similar.

Comment: @blip "The best white supremacist is still a far below the worst anti-nazi. – blip"  That's purely ideological and justifies to justification for any and all escalation from vigilante groups.

Comment: @NPSF3000 there's a point where things become not ideological, but overwhelmingly 'the way it is'. If you don't recall, the entire planet had a war because the entire planet decided that Nazis are very, very bad people. In fact, so bad, that they are typically used as an example of the worst people ever. Yes, perhaps a little bit of hyperbole there, but I'm glad I still live in a world where *most* reasonable people know not to play silly semantic games when dealing with white supremacists.

Comment: @Blip and yet Communists killed more than Nazi's did - and it's claimed that communist flags were waved by counter protesters.  Heck, we nearly had a *nuclear* war with them (in addition to Korea, Vietnam etc).

The driver of the car is an idiot/murder/terrorist, but that's not exclusive to the far right.  Anyone remember James Thomas Hodgkinson?  

Condemn bad behaviour, don't be blinded so much by 'the bad guys' that you pick up worse bedfellows in the process.  if you justify one group, you justify them *all*.

Comment: @NPSF3000 the difference here is that there is no group advocating for USSR-style communist rule in the US complete with mass genocide. Antifa isn't staging protests to promote any sort of stance on that. They are simply against White Supremacists--a group that *is* advocating for Nazi-style rule...sometimes including mass genocide. And note, nowhere did I *justify* Antifa. I'm saying you can't claim "everyone is equally bad" as that's both politically, and intellectually dishonest. I'm fine with criticism pointed at Antifa. I'm not fine with saying "they started it".

Comment: @blip so you're completely ignore the assassination attempt on your own government?  Good to know how balanced your perspective is.

Comment: @NPSF3000 are you referring to the DC shooter? Did you just tell me not to group all of the Nazis in with the sole car driver? Your logic escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, I can see lots of reasons why anybody who believes there is such a thing as a "white race" would at least be considered to be out of touch with medical science. And since just about every definition of *White Nationalism* includes the believe in the existence of a "white race", it seems one of their main premises is as flawed as believing in a flat earth.

The concept of race as a biological phenomenon has run its course since there is absolutely no scientific evidence to sustain such a notion.

One can argue for the use of *race* as a social construct, but in that case, skin colour has as much to do with it as shoe size.

References are easy to find, but here are some examples of articles trying to explain why biological race is nonsense:

[A Scientific American article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/race-is-a-social-construct-scientists-argue/)

> Science would favor Du Bois. Today, the mainstream belief among scientists is that race is a social construct without biological meaning.

[A paper by Alan R. Templeton on NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3737365/)

> Using the two most commonly used biological concepts of race, chimpanzees are indeed subdivided into races but humans are not.

[An AAPA statement that was published in the American Journal of Physical Anthropology,](http://physanth.org/about/position-statements/biological-aspects-race/)

> There is great genetic diversity within all human populations. Pure races, in the sense of genetically homogenous populations, do not exist in the human species today, nor is there any evidence that they have ever existed in the past.

Comment: That point where categorical differentiation of individuals based on particular attributes or characteristics is marginalized because it doesn't match the biological methodologies.

Comment: I am very glad that there was a genetic bottleneck in Africa before the _Homo sapiens sapiens_ dispora. Could you imagine the racism in our civilisation we'd have to overcome if we weren't all genetically compatible?

Comment: @DrunkCynic Your comment is a sentence fragment. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Doesn't white as being discussed relate more to culture than skin color or race?  Black also isn't about skin color as much as culture.  We've with malice aforethought become a cultural salad bowl of a nation.  The white portion of the salad doesn't appear to appreciate this in that they view their culture as being disrespected.

Comment: @TomO The concept of _white race_ comes from the definitions given for White Nationalism. If they don't mean _race_ they should use another word...